# Superclass static method returning 2 different subclasses

Tags: java

This is bad programming practice but I've been asked to do it as part of a larger assignment.

I am creating a superclass and then 2 subclasses. There is a static method in the superclass that should return either of the 2 subclasses depending on the result. How would I go about writing this method?

For example I need to do something like this

```
public abstract class Superclass{
    public static subclass? createFromFilename(String fileName){
            if(1==1)
               return subclass1;
            else
                   return subclass2;
    }
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: What would you expect from `Superclass.createFromFilename("my-file")`? Indeed when you write `MySubclass.createFromFilename("other-file")` that will be compiled to call `Superclass`. So, each subtype should have a creation method, which may then common implementation moved into another method. You may find abstract factories helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
public abstract superClass
{
     public static superClass getBaseClass(...)
     {
           if(...)
           {
                 return new baseClass1();//baseClass1 should derive from superClass
           }
           else
           {
                 return new baseClass2();//baseClass2 should derive from superClass
           }
     }
}
```

You can now do this

```
superClass sc=superClass.getBaseClass(..);

if(sc instanceof baseClass1)
{
     baseClass1 bc1=(baseClass1)sc;
     //work with bc1...
}

if(sc instanceof baseClass2)
{
     baseClass2 bc2=(baseClass2)sc;
     //work with bc2...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you want to return the [class type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), you can do that by writing the subclass name and appending a `.class` to get the class type. A proper return type would be the type `Class` with a [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) limiting the result to Superclass and its subclasses.

```
public static Class<? extends Superclass> createFromFileName(String fileName) {
     if (fileName.equals("A")) {
          return SubclassA.class;
     } else {
          return SubclassB.class;
     }
}
```

If, however, you want to return an object of the respective class, you can do that by simply return a new instance and set the return type to `Superclass`:

```
public static Superclass createFromFileName(String fileName) {
     if (fileName.equals("A")) {
          new SubclassA();
     } else {
          new SubclassB();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to determine the return type as a result of the execution of the method. This is not possible to do. So you have to bear having the common superclass return type. BTW if you know at compile time the proper return type, why dont you change (having 2 methods?) the method to reflect that?